# Synths as Audio Sound interface

Tags: ableton-live

I have an Analog Four MK1 connected directly to the computer and to the speakers and used as an Audio Interface in Ableton.
I will get now an Elektron Analog Rytm MKII. and I wonder if I can play both or I should add an Audio Interface like Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 (2nd Gen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you route the audio already through the computer this should be easy with OB2.

Or when you don’t want to use OB2 yet, you can also connect the main outs of AR to the inputs of the A4 so you can mix it in.

You can route the rytm through the analog four inputs and do it that way. just turn on the volume (FX track + OSC1 /Ext In).